# How to get the longest common sub string of all strings in List<String> where the strings are of different lengths?

Tags: java, string, list, collections, java-stream

Given a list of strings of the same length and no special characters:

`List<String> myStringArray = List.of( "xxxyyyjjjabcdefg", xxxyyyjjjabcdefg", "xxxyyyxxxabcdefg")`;

I can find the longest common sub string of the list:

```
String lengthOfAllStrings = myStringArray.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get();  
List<char[]> myCharArray = myStringArray.stream().map(String::toCharArray).collect(Collectors.toList());  
StringBuilder longestCommonSubString = StringBuilder();  
StringBuilder currentLongestSubString = new StringBuilder();  
  
for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfAllStrings.length(); i++) {
int finalI = i;
if(myCharArray.stream().anyMatch((a) -> a[finalI] == ( (myCharArray.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x[finalI]))).values().size == 1 ? (myCharArray.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x[finalI]))).entrySet().iterator().next().getKey() : '!'))) {  
  longestCommonSubString.append((myCharArray.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy( x -> x[finalI]))).entrySet().iterator().next().getKey());  
 } else {  
  currentLongestSubString.append(longestCommonSubString);  
  longestCommonSubString = new StringBuilder();  
 }  
}  
System.out.println("The Longest Common Sub String = " + Stream.of(longestCommonSubString.toString(), currentLongestSubString.toString()).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get());
```

Output: The Longest Common Sub String = abcdefg

but what if the list contains strings of different length:

`List<String> myStringArray = List.of( "xxxyyy", xxxyyy", "yyy");`

Desired Output: The Longest Sub String = yyy

Also, is there a way to do all this with a one liner and not use a for loop ?

Comment: Do you really think that performing multi-step stream operations inside sub-expressions inside an `if` condition has an acceptable readability? Not to speak of the efficiency of performing the same stream operation multiple times in a row. And why do you convert all strings into `char[]` arrays at the beginning? As far as I can see, the only thing you’re doing with the arrays, is the equivalent of a simple `charAt` call which you can do on the original strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LongestCommonSubstring {
    public static String findLongestCommonSubstring(List<String> strings) {
        if (strings == null || strings.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }

        String firstString = strings.get(0);
        int maxLength = firstString.length();
        String longestCommonSubstring = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= maxLength; j++) {
                String substring = firstString.substring(i, j);
                boolean isCommon = strings.stream().allMatch(s -> s.contains(substring));
                if (isCommon && substring.length() > longestCommonSubstring.length()) {
                    longestCommonSubstring = substring;
                }
            }
        }

        return longestCommonSubstring;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myStringArray = List.of("xxxyyy", "xxxyyy", "yyy");
        String longestCommonSubstring = findLongestCommonSubstring(myStringArray);
        System.out.println("The Longest Common Substring = " + longestCommonSubstring);
    }
}
```

This code will work for lists of strings with different lengths and will find the longest common substring among them.

As for doing this with a one-liner and without a for loop, it's not practical because finding the longest common substring among different-length strings typically requires comparing all possible substrings, which cannot be efficiently accomplished with a one-liner or without some form of iteration. Hope this can help :)